# Scrapy randomly return empty response body

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping an [online store](http://shop.coles.com.au/online/national), but I randomly miss products. I did some investigation and found that some `Request` returned empty `response.body` although `status` is `200`, and all empty responses were from `FormRequest`.

I tried to set `download_timeout` to a larger number i.e. 1800s. The issue still remains.

I really have no clue about what causes the issue. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
import scrapy

class TestcSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "testc"
# allowed_domains = ["http://shop.coles.com.au/"]
start_urls = ["http://shop.coles.com.au/online/national"]

def parse(self, response):
    for div in response.xpath('//ul[@id="aisleMenu"]/li/div')[1:]:
        a = div.xpath('h2/a')
        category_name = a.xpath('text()').extract_first().strip()
        category_urlName = a.xpath('@href').re(r'/([^/]+)/*$')[0]


        for li in div.xpath('ul/li'):
            if (li.xpath('@class').extract_first()):
                subcategory_name = li.xpath('a/text()').extract_first().strip()
                subcategory_urlName = li.xpath('a/@href').re(r'/([^/]+)/*$')[0]
            else:
                subsubcategory_name = li.xpath('a/text()').extract_first().strip()
                subsubcategory_urlName = li.xpath('a/@href').re(r'/([^/]+)/*$')[0]

                url = self.make_url(category_urlName, subcategory_urlName, subsubcategory_urlName)
                request = scrapy.Request(url, cookies={'ColesSearchPageSizeCookie': '100'}, callback = self.get_products)
                request.meta['category'] = [category_name, category_urlName]
                request.meta['subcategory'] = [subcategory_name, subcategory_urlName]
                request.meta['subsubcategory'] = [subsubcategory_name, subsubcategory_urlName]

                yield request


def get_products(self, response):

    check = response.xpath('//div[@class="list-view viewContainer clearfix searchEspot"]/div[@class="outer-prod prodtile"]').extract_first()
    if check is None:
        print response.url
        print response.meta
        print response.body
        print '------------'

    if response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination clearfix"]/ul[@class="navigator"]/li[@class="next"]').extract_first() is not None:
        data_refresh = response.xpath('//div[@id="searchDisplay"]/@data-refresh').extract_first()
        formdata = dict([
            (x.split(':')[0].strip(), x.split(':')[1].strip("' "))
            for x in data_refresh.strip("{}").split(',')
        ])

        formdata['beginIndex'] = str(int(formdata['beginIndex']) + int(formdata['pageSize']))

        url = self.make_next_url(response.meta['category'][1], response.meta['subcategory'][1])
        request = scrapy.FormRequest(url, cookies={'ColesSearchPageSizeCookie': '100'}, formdata = formdata, callback = self.get_products)
        request.meta['category'] = response.meta['category']
        request.meta['subcategory'] = response.meta['subcategory']
        request.meta['subsubcategory'] = response.meta['subsubcategory']

        yield request

def make_url(self, category_urlName, subcategory_urlName, subsubcategory_urlName):
    return 'http://shop.coles.com.au/online/national/{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(category_urlName, subcategory_urlName, subsubcategory_urlName)


def make_next_url(self, category_urlName, subcategory_urlName):
    return 'http://shop.coles.com.au/online/national/{0}/{1}/ColesCategoryView'.format(category_urlName, subcategory_urlName)
```

Comment: You need to add some code that can replicate the issue

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I made a simple test code. I found the number of missing pages seems related to the speed of sending requests.

Comment: Have you enabled [AutoThrottle](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html)? Have you set a reasonable [DOWNLOAD_DELAY](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?#std:setting-DOWNLOAD_DELAY)?

Comment: @paultrmbrth, I enabled autothrottle, but I still got empty bodies. I will try download_delay. The thing is these 2 still won't guarantee no missing pages, will they? Also only `FormRequest`s have the issue, and all `Request`s are fine.

Comment: You cannot guarantee a website response, that's true. If only FormRequests' response have trouble, how have you tested them? do they work in scrapy shell? Sometimes, websites don't work well with concurrent requests > 1, especially if forms keep state

Comment: @paultrmbrth I checked every response to see if its body is empty. Some of FormRequests are fine, but some are empty. The store uses post to load contents on next page. So I guess I have to use FormRequest. Is it possilbe to send only one FormRequest a time?

Comment: Hi @Harrison have you found any solution for this problem ? i also seems to be having the same issue but only happen when I run scrapy within airflow.